# Custom camera displays wrong orientation

Tags: android, user-interface, camera, orientation

I followed the guide on the Android developers website on how to make a custom camera but the orientation is 90 degrees off. When the camera is in landscape mode (turning left) it displays how it should - however, when it's in landscape after  turning right it displays the view upside down.

I did some reading online and tried a few things but none of them seem to work. For example, I tried using mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90), which works initially, but now it's 90 degrees off in landscape mode. Also, when I save the image it still saves it with the wrong orientation.

I have included this in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And this is the surfaceCreated() method that I'm using:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if(mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } else {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? It seems like a lot of people have faced the same issue but I haven't had any luck fixing it so far. Really grateful for any help, thank you.

Comment: "For example, I tried using mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90), which works initially, but now it's 90 degrees off in landscape mode" -- reverse landscape is 180 degrees, not 90 degrees, off from standard landscape. You cannot hard-code an orientation. You need to determine the orientation value to use based on the device orientation. "when I save the image it still saves it with the wrong orientation" -- some cameras will store an EXIF header telling the image viewer to rotate the image. `BitmapFactory` ignores this, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know of any material I can look at for the orientation bug?

Comment: I do not know what bug you are referring to. The only bug that I am aware of with respect to what you have posted is your hard-coded `90` in `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)`. If that is what you are referring to, you might wish to look at [the documentation for `setDisplayOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29). If you are referring to `BitmapFactory` not honoring the EXIF orientation header, I'd describe that as more of a missing feature, and by definition, there's no documentation regarding missing features.

Comment: Tried the code in the link but it messes up when I go into landscape mode (same as before). Surely there are workarounds for the BitmapFactory issue? I'm tired so I will look into it tomorrow and let you know if I get anywhere with it - thanks for the info!